# Cosine Similarity

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, similarity, cosine-similarity

I was reading and came across this formula:

[image]

The formula is for cosine similarity. I thought this looked interesting and I created a numpy array that has user_id as row and item_id as column. For instance, let `M` be this matrix:

```
M = [[2,3,4,1,0],[0,0,0,0,5],[5,4,3,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1]]
```

Here the entries inside the matrix are ratings the people `u` has given to item `i` based on row `u` and column `i`. I want to calculate this cosine similarity for this matrix between items (rows). This should yield a 5 x 5 matrix I believe. I tried to do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(M)
item_mean_subtracted = df.sub(df.mean(axis=0), axis=1)
similarity_matrix = item_mean_subtracted.fillna(0).corr(method="pearson").values
```

However, this does not seem right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation of the adjusted cosine similarity:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

M = np.asarray([[2, 3, 4, 1, 0], 
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 5], 
                [5, 4, 3, 0, 0], 
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

M_u = M.mean(axis=1)
item_mean_subtracted = M - M_u[:, None]
similarity_matrix = 1 - squareform(pdist(item_mean_subtracted.T, 'cosine'))
```

**Remarks:**

- I'm taking advantage of NumPy [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to subtract the mean.
- If `M` is a sparse matrix, you could do something like ths: `M.toarray()`.
- From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html):

  > Y = pdist(X, 'cosine')
  >   Computes the cosine distance between vectors u and v,
  >   1 − u⋅v / (||u||<sub>2</sub>||v||<sub>2</sub>)
  >   where ||∗||<sub>2</sub> is the 2-norm of its argument *, and u⋅v is the dot product of u and v.
- Array transposition is performed through the [T](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) method.

**Demo:**

```
In [277]: M_u
Out[277]: array([ 2. ,  1. ,  2.4,  1. ])

In [278]: item_mean_subtracted
Out[278]: 
array([[ 0. ,  1. ,  2. , -1. , -2. ],
       [-1. , -1. , -1. , -1. ,  4. ],
       [ 2.6,  1.6,  0.6, -2.4, -2.4],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])

In [279]: np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

In [280]: similarity_matrix
Out[280]: 
array([[ 1.  ,  0.87,  0.4 , -0.68, -0.72],
       [ 0.87,  1.  ,  0.8 , -0.65, -0.91],
       [ 0.4 ,  0.8 ,  1.  , -0.38, -0.8 ],
       [-0.68, -0.65, -0.38,  1.  ,  0.27],
       [-0.72, -0.91, -0.8 ,  0.27,  1.  ]])
```

Comment: I believe the adjusted cosine similarity values should be between -1 and 1 right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I misread the formula. Please take a look again at my edited answer, I think that now the adjusted cosine similarity is correctly implemented.

Comment: does this group the users for like u in U that the formula asks for?

Comment: so like for each user (row in original matrix) we need to find the other users who rated the current item we are looking at

Comment: Yes, it does. Notice that the shape of similarity matrix is (I, I), being I the number of items.

Comment: ok so like if we are looking at item 2 then it finds all users who have a nonzero entry for item2 and computes the mean there for $\bar{R}_u$

Comment: Can you explain how this does this, I can't tell how it does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138481/discussion-between-mike-el-jackson-and-tonechas).