# Adjusted Cosine Similarity in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

Referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866174/cosine-similarity)

which calculates adjusted cosine similarity matrix (given the ratings matrix M having m users and n items) as below:

```
M_u = M.mean(axis=1)    
item_mean_subtracted = M - M_u[:, None]    
similarity_matrix = 1 - squareform(pdist(item_mean_subtracted.T, 'cosine'))
```

I cannot see how the **'both rated'** condition is met as per this [definition](http://www10.org/cdrom/papers/519/node14.html)

I have manually calculated the adjusted cosine similarities and they seem to differ with the values I get from above code.

Could anyone please clarify this?

Comment: You might be better of asking at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Let's first try to understand the formulation, the matrix is stored such that each row is a user and each column is an item. User is indexed by u and column is indexed by i.

Each user have different judgement rule of how good or how bad is something is. A 1 from a user could be a 3 from another user. That is why we subtract the average of each R_u, from each R_{u,i}. This is computed as item_mean_subtracted in your code. Notice that we are subtracting each element by its **row mean** to normalize the user's biasness. After which, we normalized each column (item) by dividing each column by its norm and then compute the cosine similarity between each column.

pdist(item_mean_subtracted.T, 'cosine') computes the cosine distance between the items and it is known that

> cosine similarity = 1- cosine distance

and hence that is why the code works.

Now, what if I compute it directly according to the definition directly? I have commented what is being performed in each step, try to copy and paste the code and you can compare with your calculation by printing out more intermediate steps.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from numpy.linalg import norm

M = np.asarray([[2, 3, 4, 1, 0], 
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 5], 
                [5, 4, 3, 0, 0], 
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

M_u = M.mean(axis=1)
item_mean_subtracted = M - M_u[:, None]
similarity_matrix = 1 - squareform(pdist(item_mean_subtracted.T, 'cosine'))
print(similarity_matrix)

#Computing the cosine similarity directly
n = len(M[0]) # find out number of columns(items)
normalized = item_mean_subtracted/norm(item_mean_subtracted, axis = 0).reshape(1,n) #divide each column by its norm, normalize it
normalized = normalized.T #transpose it
similarity_matrix2 = np.asarray([[np.inner(normalized[i],normalized[j] ) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]) # compute the similarity matrix by taking inner product of any two items
print(similarity_matrix2)
```

Both of the codes give the same result:

```
[[ 1.          0.86743396  0.39694169 -0.67525773 -0.72426278]
 [ 0.86743396  1.          0.80099604 -0.64553225 -0.90790362]
 [ 0.39694169  0.80099604  1.         -0.37833504 -0.80337196]
 [-0.67525773 -0.64553225 -0.37833504  1.          0.26594024]
 [-0.72426278 -0.90790362 -0.80337196  0.26594024  1.        ]]
```